# How to Close Camera after given time interval in Android?

Tags: android, camera

I have requirement where i will start the camera and user will use the camera for capturing image. but i have some more requirement which is **"close that camera activity after 1min if user does not do anything there."**
Can anybody suggest me something on that. i was thinking about killing the camera process but i dont find its quite ok. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a TimerTask to check whether any key has been pressed during 1 minute or not, Now if not then try following code to close your camera.

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    camera.stopPreview();
    isPreviewRunning = false;
    camera.release();
}
```

Killing Camera Process is not advisable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply arjun but i think you have given me the method which is usefull when i use the SurfaceView. but here i am using inbuilt camera. can you give me some other way to do that.

Comment: Yes Amol, that is for SurfaceView, I dont know much about inbuilt camera using. sorry for that dear

Comment: ok no problem. if you find anytime my answer please do reply thanks again